# void type not allowed when adding a button with an action listener?

Tags: java, swing, button

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4, 4, 10, 10);

//Add the grid to the frame
frame.setLayout(grid);

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    frame.add(new JButton("Button: " + i)
            .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("you clicked me!");
        }

    }));

}
```

I was wondering why it keeps giving me trouble, when adding an action listener to each button on the grid.

Basically I am trying to print the position of the button on the grid. 
ex: button 3 is position (0, 3)

Comment: You can't chain the new JButton() and addActionListener(), because addActionListener() doesn't return a value (it's defind as void). One solution might be to create method that creates the button, registers the ActionListener and returns the button...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: void type not allowed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding to the frame the result of the `addActionListener` method, which is [void](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)).

This should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    JButton button = new JButton("Button: " + i);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("you clicked me!");
        }
    });
    frame.add(button);
}
```

Comment: question. would this give me the position of the button that was clicked, or the position of the grid layout? thanks btw

Comment: i'm not sure I understood what you're looking for here, but maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580243/get-position-of-the-button-on-gridlayout) will help..

Answer (score 0):

JButton.addActionListener() doesn't return JButton. It returns void. To fix create a new JButton and then add it.

```
frame.setLayout(grid);

for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    JButton j = new JButton("Button: " + i);
    j.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("you clicked me!");
        }

    }));
    frame.add(j);
}
```

Hope this helps.